# ajax request in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

```
                <table  align="left" width="100%" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form">
                        <table width="500" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <form name="frmlist" id="frmlist" action="check.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <table  width="802" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="20">1</td>
                                                    <td width="120"><span class="form_title">Brand Name<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span></span></td>
                                                    <td><select name="brand" id="Category_type" onchange="get_states();"><?php
                                                    if($count>0){
                                                        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){ 
                                                        echo '<option value='.$row['uniq_id'].'>'.$row['brand_name'].'</option>';
                                                    }}?>
                                                    </select></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr height="10"></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="3" width="1000"><textarea cols="1000" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="1000">
                                                        <div id="get_state"></div></textarea>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            <script>
                                                var editor;
                                                function createEditor( languageCode ) {
                                                if ( editor )
                                                    editor.destroy();
                                                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                                                    extraPlugins: 'stylesheetparser',contentsCss: 'css/main.css',stylesSet: []
                                                    });
                                                }
                                                // At page startup, load the default language:
                                                createEditor( '' );
                                            </script>
                                            <div>
                                        </table>
                                            <input type="submit" name="partner_1" value="SUBMIT" class="sub" ></div>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>          
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_states() { // Call to ajax function
    var Category_type = $('#Category_type').val();
    console.log(Category_type);
    var dataString = "Category_type="+Category_type;
    //console.log(Category_type);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_partner.php", // Name of the php files
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html)
        {

             $("#get_state").html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

first there is a dropdown which brings the value from the database , When user click on any value , It send a ajax request through which I get the value and get the html from it place it between the **div which has id get_state** 
I am using a check editor so that the user can see and edit his work 
i have checked it on my console and its bringing the data so please anybody can help me

Comment: why are you updating an element inside your CkEditor instance? Why not just let CkEditor do the magic, using CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml(html);  Because what happens if a user deletes all the content from the textarea? Then you will not have a div with id 'get_state' anymore...

Comment: I just need one more favour , during my ajax request , If i select 2nd option , the ajax send the html and if i select any other option it will add those line and so on , so how to make the div empty whenever the user click on any other select value

Comment: @ReinderWit please give me a ans

Comment: You could try to kill the current instance and reload: CKEDITOR.remove(editor) and then call your createEditor function.